# Change state of array of maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm not the best with using the map function, so sorry about the easy question. I have an array with state that contains a map in each index, with certain fields from each map corresponding to an input field. I have a function to change state of the map, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Would appreciate some help with getting this to actually work

Here is an example of the data type that the array holds `[{"topic": "some string", "description": "some string", "id": 0}, {"topic": "some string", "description": "some string", "id": 1}, ...]`. Every `id` in the map of an array is unique

Here is the array
`const [deckInfo, setDeckInfo] = React.useState([])`

Here is the function to change the state of the map:

```
function handleDeckInfoChange(index, e) {
        setDeckInfo(prevState => ([
            ...prevState.map(card => ({
                ...card = new Map(Object.entries(card)),
                ...card.get("id") === index
                ? card.set([e.target.name], e.target.value)
                : card
            }))
        ]))
    }
```

Here is how I'm rendering the component for the input fields

```
<ul className="decks">
    {deckInfo.map((flaschard, num) => {
        return (
            <li className="review-flashcard-wrapper"> 
                <EditFlashcard key={num} flaschard={flaschard} editState={handleDeckInfoChange} />
            </li>
                            )
        }
     )}
</ul>
```

This is the code for the component which contains the input fields

```
const EditFlashcard = ({flaschard, editState}) => {
    flaschard = new Map(Object.entries(flaschard))
    return (
            <div className="review-flashcard" >
                <div className="review-flashcard-topic">
                    <input type="text" name="topic" value={flaschard.get("topic")} onChange={ (event) => { editState(flaschard.get("id"), event) } } ></input>
                </div>
                <div className="review-flashcard-desc">
                    <input type="text" name="description" value={flaschard.get("description")} onChange={ (event) => { editState(flaschard.get("id"), event) } } ></input>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}

export default EditFlashcard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
function handleDeckInfoChange(index, e) {
    setDeckInfo(prev => {
        const newState = prev.map(card => {
            if (card.id == index) return {
                ...card,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }
            return card
        })
        return newState;
    })
}

const EditFlashcard = ({ flaschard, editState }) => {
    return (
        <div className="review-flashcard">
            <div className="review-flashcard-topic">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="topic"
                    value={flaschard.topic}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        editState(flaschard.id, event);
                    }}
                ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="review-flashcard-desc">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="description"
                    value={flaschard.description}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        editState(flaschard.id, event);
                    }}
                ></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-leftpad-xjjggj?file=/src/App.js)